# What is the value of $\int_{-1}^{1} P(\sin x)P'(\sin x)dx$?

Tags: trigonometry, integration, polynomials

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $P(x)=x^4+x^2+1.$  Then $\int_{-1}^{1} P(\sin x)P'(\sin x)dx=?$

My Attempt: $\int_{-1}^{1} P(\sin x)P'(\sin x)dx= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[\sin ^4x+\sin ^2x+1][4\sin ^3x+2 \sin x]dx=.....$  .

Am I going in the right direction or Is there any other better approach to tackle the problem? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $P$ is even, so your integrand $f(x)=P(\sin x)P'(\sin x)$ is odd.

Hence, without any calculation:
$$
\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=0.
$$